# ngx-extended-pdf-viewer problem with image position in base64 document

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

I am trying to visualize a base64 document through the ngx-extended-pdf-viewer library, however, when the library shows me the document, the images in it appear in a different place than the one I defined in the original document. The original document looks like this:
[image]

But the library shows me like this:
[image]

I would like to know if there is any way to preserve the original format of the document or if there is any property that allows it. The code I am using is the following:

```
<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer [base64Src]="srcTMP2" [useBrowserLocale]="true" [showDownloadButton]="false"
            [enablePrint]="false" [showPrintButton]="false" [textLayer]="true" delayFirstView="1000" language="es-Es">
</ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open a bug at https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues. Maybe you've run into a CSS problem, but if not, that's clearly a bug. Please check you document also on https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html. That's the base library I'm using. Does it show correctly there?